# Group Session in Django Channels

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I'm looking for a solution where I want to create a group with n number of users and let them-users join the group. and then finally, delete this group once the work is complete. (the creator of the group can delete this or when everyone from the group disconnects).

I have been thinking to design this for the last 3-4 days but I'm not able to.

I'm building the transcriber app and this group is to maintain sessions on each topic. For every new topic/scenario, a new group/session is required.

The question is -

How and when should I delete the group?

Suppose I created a group and then everyone joins, I can maintain a database and delete this group when everyone disconnects from this group, somehow I don't think this to be the best option

Can anyone guide me to design the best possible option?

Will provide more details if required.

My transcriber code is working fine, I'm only looking to set a session so that I can get audio to text per session.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly

maybe if you add for example **work_status** for this group model and when Every one leave the group or disconnects you can check if this work done to delete it or not

and when users done the work you can update this field to **True**

I think in this way you will not delete group in wrong way or make a mistake

also you can run a **Cron** job to check **work_status** in specific time

Comment: What if I created a group, I joined and before others join the group I disconnects from this group. Here I'm checking active users in group. It is not possible that everyone in the group will join so I can't wait for everyone to disconnects.

Comment: you are thinking in the right path, but this solution will not always work, it is correct in some situation.

Comment: it will be not only one condation, this just one step

Comment: Yes, this is only one step but can we think of other conditions too?